# MySQL multiple count based on two column with multiple GROUP BY in single table

Tags: mysql

I have a query like below, it is working fine but not optimized, since it takes 1.5 sec to run. How to make this to an optimized result?

```
select h.keyword_id,

    ( select count(DISTINCT(user_id)) from history where category_id = 6
      and h.keyword_id=keyword_id group by keyword_id ) as cat_6,

    ( select count(DISTINCT(user_id)) from history  where category_id = 7
      and h.keyword_id = keyword_id group by keyword_id ) as cat_7

    from 

    history h group by h.keyword_id
```

**History table**

```
his_id  keyword_id category_id user_id

1       1           6           12
2       1           6           12
3       1           7           12
4       1           7           12
5       2           6           13
6       2           6           13
7       2           7           13
8       3           6           13
```

**Result:**

```
keyword_id  cat_6       cat_7

1           2            2 (unique users)
2           2            1
3           1            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your query like this:

```
select h.keyword_id,
count(distinct if(category_id = 6, user_id, null)) as cat_6,
count(distinct if(category_id = 7, user_id, null)) as cat_7
from 
history h 
group by h.keyword_id
```

Your desired result based on the sample data is by the way false. In each keyword_id there's always just one distinct user_id.

- you can see the query in action in an sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d63c/1/0)

For more optimization, you'd have to post the result of `show create table history` and the output of `explain <your_query>;`